# Why is this bibliography unnumbered?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, numbering, natbib

Can anyone please tell me how to numbered the bibliography in this template (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/international-journal-of-recirculating-aquaculture/tkqfgxscsrtk) I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Are you planning to submit to the International Journal of Recirculating Aquaculture? If yes, then you will need to use their style of citations, which seems to be Author-Year (so not numbered). If you don't plan to submit to that journal, then why are you using this template and not another one that already has numbered citations?

Comment: Hi, I do not plan to submit to the International Journal of Recirculating Aquaculture. I have to write an academic journal for my school with a style very similar to this template, but I need the bibliography to be numbered.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of deleting the `biblatex` tag, as your posting does not appear to be related in any way to the work performed by the `biblatex` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting just the bibliography numbered (keeping the citations the same), or do you want the citations replaced with numbers as well?

If you want the second, you can change your package usage to:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

and you will get output like

```
References
[1] Author... title...
```

If that's not what you're looking for, see if the info on this page helps you out: https://sharelatex.psi.ch/learn/Natbib_bibliography_styles

Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much :)

Comment: I've got a lot of help off of here over the years, glad I could pay some of it back.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the first few lines of the `thebibliography` environment:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{xx}
\harvarditem[Avnimelech]{Avnimelech}{2009}{avn2009}
Avnimelech, Y. 2009. {Biofloc Technology - A Practical Guidebook. The World Aquaculture Society, Baton Rouge, Louisiana, United States.}.

\harvarditem[Churchill and Elmer]{Churchill and Elmer}{1999}{chuelm1999} 
Churchill, P. and Elmer, D. 1999. {Hydrogen Sulfide Odor Control in Wastewater Collection Systems}. {\em New England Water Environment Association Journal}, {\bf (33)1}: 57-63.

\harvarditem[Crockett et~al]{Crockett, Lawrence, Moeckel, Lingfelter, and Patnaik}{2012}{cro+al2012}
Crockett, J.K., Lawrence, A.L., Moeckel, J., Lingfelter, B.A, and Patnaik, S. 2012. {Ammonia, Nitrite, Nitrate Management Strategies in Zero to Limited Water Exchange Shallow Water Indoor Nursery Production Systems.} {International Conference of Recirculating Aquaculture, Roanoke, VA}.
```

To get a numbered bibliography, you will have to change the environment by hand to

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{avn2009}
Avnimelech, Y. 2009. {Biofloc Technology - A Practical Guidebook. The World Aquaculture Society, Baton Rouge, Louisiana, United States.}.

\bibitem{chuelm1999} 
Churchill, P. and Elmer, D. 1999. {Hydrogen Sulfide Odor Control in Wastewater Collection Systems}. {\em New England Water Environment Association Journal}, {\bf (33)1}: 57-63.

\bibitem{cro+al2012}
Crockett, J.K., Lawrence, A.L., Moeckel, J., Lingfelter, B.A, and Patnaik, S. 2012. {Ammonia, Nitrite, Nitrate Management Strategies in Zero to Limited Water Exchange Shallow Water Indoor Nursery Production Systems.} {International Conference of Recirculating Aquaculture, Roanoke, VA}.
```

and so on. I.e., change all instances of `\harvarditem` to `\bibitem` and omit the argument in square brackets and the first two arguments in curly braces.

Finally, if the template (or the `tellus.cls` class file) loads the `harvard` citation management package, delete the instruction (possibly `\usepackage{harvard}`) that does so and replace it with the `cite` package: `\usepackage{cite}`.

Comment: I did that and the numbers still don't show up. The output is the following: Avnimelech, Y. 2009. Biofloc Technology - A Practical Guidebook. The World Aquaculture Society, Baton Rouge, Louisiana, United States..

Comment: @HunterS.Dogmpsonm - Did you also delete the instruction that loads either the `harvard` or the `natbib` package? And. did you recompile the document twice after making the changes?

Answer (score 0):

This template does not use bibtex or any other automated tool for the bibliography. It just puts them all in the bibliography part manually. If you would like to number them, you would have to do that manually too.

I would highly encourage you to look into the usage of bibtex or another automated reference manager. The idea is that you put all of your references in one file, and then call them with the `\cite{}` command in your document.

There's plenty of good sources and templates online on how to do that, I would start [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex).

Comment: Hello, I tried to modify the template and use bibtex, and although it works, the bibliography comes out without numbering. I looked in the configuration file tellus.cls where the bibliography is configured and I didn't find where the numbering is removed.